# "User session ID does not exist" - Oracle

Tags: oracle

When using alter system kill session, I have the ora-00030 alert as per subject.

Therefore I am not able to kill it, is there any other method to kill an Oracle session?

Why is this happening? When executing "`select sid, serial# from v$session where sid=.....`", I do get an output

Comment: What is the output you get for the SELECT?

Comment: It is giving me "sid = 125 and serail# = 12559".

Comment: The ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION command will mark the session as to be killed, but sometimes will not be able to kill it. If you want to kill it immediately (make sure there will be no data lost), then you can force it by adding the IMMEDIATE to the end of the command.